# Google Play. Publish an app only to new users

Tags: android, google-play, publish

I have a published app in google play. Is it possible to publish an app update, that will affects only the new users? So the existing users will not be able to update.

Thanks!

Comment: But why? You can use part update for a new release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "new users" you mean the normal public that did not install your app yet, then no. That is not possible. Once you publish your app, anybody will be able to access the new version.

You could potentially publish it under a different app-id as a brand new app that just happens to be an almost exact copy of your old app, then there will be no update path from one to the other, but there is no way that "new users" wouldn't find your original app first, or that old users wonder what that weird new clone app is.

If you want an app that is only available to a specific set of people for testing, or create different apps for experimenting, you can read up on it here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/12053285

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible and is related to **[versionCode](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning)**.
Basically, if you upload an app with versionCode lower than already installed by your users, they will not be able to update, just new user will.

Google explain some use cases where it would be used:

> In some specific situations, you might wish to upload a version of
> your app with a lower versionCode than the most recent version. For
> example, if you are publishing multiple APKs, you might have pre-set
> versionCode ranges for specific APKs. For more about assigning
> versionCode values for multiple APKs, see [Multiple APK Support](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks#VersionCodes).

Comment: Unfortunately that is no longer true. I just tried to publish an app with a lower version code and I get stuck on the last step, with the following error:
"You can't rollout this release because it doesn't allow any existing users to upgrade to the newly added app bundles."